# How to create a list of values inside application.properties file and how to retrieve that list inside controller class using springboot

Tags: list, spring-boot, loops, controller, application.properties

My requirement is to create a list of values inside application.properties file.

```
com.mail = aaaa, bbbb, cccc
```

I want to retrieve these values in my controller class and iterator over each value and should check with the requestbody/queryparam values which gets, when hitting an API

Consider I have an API

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/response")
public class HomeController {
@PostMapping("/postbody")
public String postBody(@RequestBody String fullName) {
   //here I have to validate the fullName with the list I created in the application.properties
Eg: if(fullname.equals(aaaa) or if(fullname.equals(bbbb) or if(fullname.equals(cccc)
// I want to iterator over the list to check any value is matching with fullName.
}}
```

**How to declare list of values inside application.properties? How to retrieve that list inside controller class? Post retrieving how to iterate over the list to check whether it matches with requestbody/queryparam value?**

Please provide me with solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Split the list using a comma as the delimiter.

```
private String[] mailList;

public HomeController( @Value("${com.mail}") final String mail) {
    mailList = mail.split(",")
}
```

You can now use mailList inside postBody method.

Comment: Please can you code for getting values from list rather an array? 
private List<String> mailList;

If I declare list and if I try to iterate it is returning only 1 value which is at first and remaining comma separated values are not getting fetched.@ankit

Answer (score 0):

In Application. properties   you will add  the parameter  with values separated with ','

```
com.mail = aaaa,bbbb,cccc

in the controller  will get the Values 
    @Value("${com.mail}")
    private List<String> mailListValues;
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/response")
public class HomeController {

 @Value("${com.mail}")
    private List<Object> mailListValues;

@PostMapping("/postbody")
public String postBody(@RequestBody String fullName) {
 if(!mailListValues.isEmpty()){
long countOfMatch = mailListValues.stream()
.filter(item->item.equals(fullName)).count();

  if(countOfMatch >0)
// your Business .....
}
}}
```

please check images
[image]
[image]

Comment: @Value("${com.mail}")
    private List<String> mailListValues;

This mailListValues is not taking values from application.properties if given with comma separated.

Comment: com.mail=aaa,bbb,ccc 

@Value("${com.mail}") private List<String> mailListValues;

In output its returning the mailListValues with length 1 i.e aaa
remaining values are not considered for list

Comment: if we declare as array it works with comma separated but if we declare as List its not working with comma separated values... Please let me know how to make the controller to recognize the list from application.properties @Amro

Comment: @justinaantony    please check the images  , i added it

Answer (score 0):

use comma separated values in application.properties

```
com.mail = aaaa, bbbb, cccc
```

Java code for access

```
@Value("${com.email}")
String[] mailList;
```

It worked.